# Prometheus expression has data, but a rule for that expression has no data

Tags: prometheus

I have a prometheus expression:

```
(
  max(aws_sqs_approximate_number_of_messages_visible_average{queue_name="queue-1"}) 
+ max(aws_sqs_approximate_number_of_messages_not_visible_average{queue_name="queue-2"})) 
/ sum(kube_pod_container_status_ready{container="worker"}
)
```

Which evaluates correctly in the prometheus UI, however I have a rule which evaluates to this exact expression:

```
- name: tasks
  rules:
  - expr: <expr>
    labels:
      deployment: worker
      kubernetes_name: worker 
      kubernetes_namespace: default
      namespace: default
    record: app:tasks_per_worker
```

This rule always returns "No datapoints found" in the prometheus UI.

Why is this?

global scrape and evaluation interval are both 15s

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus rules evaluate *at the current time*, cloudwatch data is often very delayed, so while you can get a graph of historical data, the value of the current data is always null.

You can fix it by adding an offset, e.g:

```
(
  max(aws_sqs_approximate_number_of_messages_visible_average{queue_name="queue-1"} offset 10m) 
+ max(aws_sqs_approximate_number_of_messages_not_visible_average{queue_name="queue-2"}) offset 10m) 
/ sum(kube_pod_container_status_ready{container="worker"} offset 10m
)
```